# How matrix came in Bilinear, Quadratic form and Inner product

Tags: linear-transformations, inner-products, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

When I read about Bilinear, Quadratic form and Inner product I saw

> **Bilinear**: If $\beta=(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)$ is an ordered basis for a metric vector space $V$, then a bilinear form is completely determined by the $n\times n$ matrix of values $M_{\beta}=(a_{i,j})=\left(⟨b_i,b_j⟩\right)$ This is referred to as the matrix of the form $($or the matrix of V$)$ with respect to the ordered basis $\beta$.
>   **Inner Product**: If $⟨x,y⟩$ defines an inner product, then we can write $⟨x,y⟩=x^TAy$ where $A=(a_{ij})$ is symmetric positive definite and $a_{ij}=⟨e_i,e_j⟩$.
>   **Quadratic form**: A quadratic form over a field $K$ is a map $q:V\rightarrow K$ from a finite dimensional $K$ vector space to $K$ such that $q(av)=a^2q(v)\forall v\in V,\forall k\in K$ we can write $q(x)=x^TAx$ where $A = (a_{ij})$ be the $n×n$ matrix over $K$ whose entries are the coefficients of $q$.

Whenever I saw a matrix I imagine some kind of transformation. And it always happen with right multiplication. I never saw any transformation with left multiplication even I don't know is it really meaningful or not$?$ **Can you provide an example of a transformation with left multiplication**

$\color{red}{\text{Why this similarity$(*^TA* )$ pop up in these forms}?}$ Eventually these matrices are quite interesting. Because their properties or axioms which they have to follow are also reflect in those matrices.
**Question $2$**: Binary quadratic forms are of the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ represented by the symmetric matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}$$ I knew it from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form). But I am curious about the general equation of the second degree $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$. Can $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$ also be written as a matrix$?$ Because if it $\color{red}{\text{is possible}}$ than I have an idea to make it diagonalization which will give me the standard form of that general equation.
Thanks for your time. Thanks in advance .

Comment: $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$ cannot be expressed by a matrix, because if you plug in 0, the result ist $f \neq 0$.

Comment: The general conic equation can be expressed as a matrix multiplication if you use homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: @amd Sir Can you give me some details on "The general conic equation can be expressed as a matrix multiplication if you use homogeneous coordinates." Thanks again

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Matrix_notation

Comment: Diagonalizing the associated matrix in various ways is a common method for producing a standard-form equation from the general one, but note that the standard form varies depending on the type of conic. Indeed, the process of repeatedly completing squares in the original equation is itself a form of diagonalization. It will be interesting to see what you’ve come up with.

Comment: Thanks for you response @amd Sir. Can you help me to figure out $\color{red}{\text{Why this similarity$(∗^TA∗)$ pop up in these forms}}?$

Comment: Try looking at bilinear and quadratic forms as generalizations (and transformations to other bases) of the dot product of two vectors instead of in terms of a linear transformation that the matrix might represent.